# How do I fix my race condition with my subprocess?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, multiprocess

I have a process that creates another process. The first process waits for the second process to print "done" then continues. However, I am getting a race condition where the first process gets stuck sometimes and can't continue after the second process prints. My code is:

First Process (process is created with ProcessBuilder):

```
if((new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())).readLine()).contains("Process done"))
        {

        } 
System.out.println("Second process completed.");
process.destroy();
```

Second Process:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    /*does some action*/
    System.out.println("Process done");
    Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Sometimes this works, but other times the first process will not get the input stream and the program will hang. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the problem that the second process prints `"done"` before the first process reads it, or that the first process gets the `inputStream` before it exists?

Comment: I believe it's the latter. I am unfamiliar with how to handle this in Java. The first process is supposed to wait for the string from the second process, though I am unsure of how synchronization should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Put a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in front of the print statement to guarantee you've polled the InputStream late enough.
2. Have the subprocess write to a file (with [`ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)), and then call `.readLine()` on the file, which will guarantee that you are not late. I would probably delete the temp file before calling `ProcessBuilder.start()`.

Also I would probably not ever call `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` for any reason.